# Есть ли вероятность того, что этот метод не дочитает байты?

Tags: java

Есть вот такой метод который помогает мне конвертировать мои файлы в `byte[]`

```
private byte[] getBytes(File zipToSend) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) zipToSend.length()];

    BufferedInputStream bos = null;

    try {
        bos = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipToSend));
        bos.read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Тут 2 вопроса :

1. Но насколько я знаю метод `read(buffer);` может и не дочитать все
   байты в буфер... Таким образом я рискую недополучить часть байтов.
2. Не рискую ли я получить OOM если указываю `byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)
   zipToSend.length()];` ? Ведь размер буфера зависит от размера
   передаваемого файла, а если это папка размером в 50+ мб ...

Вот я написал второй альтернативный метод

```
private byte[] getBytes(File zipToSend) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bos = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];

    int count;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipToSend));
        while ((count = bos.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

В этим примере я исключаю возможность потерять байты и получить OOM , но в таком случае время выполнения увеличивается в 10 раз...

Но все равно для нас конечно важнее получить полный обьем данных.

Верны ли мои убеждения насчет первого примера?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что если вы используете `ByteArrayOutputStream`, он все равно использует буфер, и не факт, что он не больше простого массива. При этом он выделяет буфер маленький, а потом увеличивает его по мере добавления байт, что значит создание нового буфера, копирование в него всех значений, что и занимает больше времени. В первом способе все нормально, но массив байт будет весить столько же, сколько и файл. Файл почитается полностью, если не случится физического отсоединения носителя, или система не решит запретит вам его читать

Comment: Думаю в вашем случае(да и вообще) второй вариант реализации, конечно, верен. Но может ошибка возникнуть в период чтения все равно, если я не ошибаюсь. Можете попробовать начать читать файл, и под дебагом, считав часть, удалить файл физически и посмотреть, что получится. Скорее всего у вас вылетит `IOException` и в итоге вы вернете не весь массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни первый, ни второй метод не исключает ни OOM, ни возможность возврата недочитанного файла, в случае какого-либо эксепшена в процессе чтения файла (хоть это, обычно маловероятно).
Чтобы не получить OOM - не читайте файл полностью в память.
Чтобы быть уверенным что весь файл прочитан - не глушите эксепшены в try/catch блоках а пробрасывайте их наверх, тогда, если в процессе чтения была какая-либо ошибка, вы получите не какой-то полузаполненный массив байт, а эксепшен, что на мой взгляд лучше.

Comment: А вот насчет OOM насколько вероятно его получить? При размере файла до 50 мб это возможно? Или файл должен быть очень большим?

Comment: Все зависит от размера кучи (heap space), который вы установили при запуске вашего приложения (опция -Xmx). Если мне не изменяет память, то на большинстве JVM, по умолчанию это около 64 МБ. Вот ссылка на англоязычную статью по теме: https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space